# JMSSerializerBundle RuntimeException: you must define a type for Entity::$field

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, jmsserializerbundle

I'm having this issue with JMSSerializerBundle. It basically gives me an exception for something that I've already done. This is my entity:

#### Edited to avoid confusion about annotation lines

```
<?php

namespace My\ProjectBundle\Entity;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * My\ProjectBundle\Entity\Music
 * 
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\ProjectBundle\Entity\MusicRepository")
 */
class Music extends Post
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string $album
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="album", type="string")
 * @Type("string")
 */
protected $album;

/**
 * @var string $artist
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="artist", type="string")
 * @Type("string")
 */
protected $artist;

/**
 * @var integer $duration
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duration", type="bigint")
 * @Type("int")
 */
protected $duration;

/**
 * @var string $title
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
 * @Type("string")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var array $genres
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="genres", type="array")
 * @Type("array")
 */
protected $genres;
```

As you can see, I've added `@Type()` annotations for the fields, but it still gives me the exception when I call:

```
$listenedMusic = $serializer->deserialize($content, 'My\ProjectBundle\Entity\Music', 'json');
```

I've checked and the `$content` variable is not empty and has all the fields mapped in JSON format.

In my Monolog files, this is the exact Exception:

```
[2012-11-29 23:39:07] request.CRITICAL: JMS\SerializerBundle\Exception\RuntimeException: 
You must define a type for My\ProjectBundle\Entity\Music::$album. (uncaught exception) 
at /vendor/jms/serializer-bundle/JMS/SerializerBundle/Serializer/GenericDeserializationVisitor.php line 177
```

Why does it still give me this exception?

Comment: You do not need to use @Type with simple variables that the serializer already gets from the Entity annotation.  The type is only needed for fields that hold related objects.. Type("array")

Comment: Well, why do I get the `Exception` that I have to set a `Type` for `$album` when it's just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by updating my entire project to `dev-master` packages. It seemed it was a bug in JMSSerializer, because without modifying any code, I stopped getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain it's because you have two comment strings with different pieces of the whole annotation. Symfony only looks at the comment string directly preceding the class member.

Try replacing:

```
/** @Type("string")*/
/**
 * @var string $album
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="album", type="string")*/
protected $album;
```

with:

```
/** 
 * @Type("string")
 *
 * @var string $album
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="album", type="string")*/
protected $album;
```

(and in every other place you have these duplicate annotation comments)

It's only a guess, but I think it'll fix it. When I tried doing this:

```
class Something
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    /**
     * 
     */
    private $id;
}
```

...Symfony gave me this error:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity 'SomeApp\SomeBundle\Entity\Something'. Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just tried different things when it didn't work. I had it in the same Annotation lines as Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var integer $duration
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duration", type="bigint")
 * @Type("int")
 */
protected $duration;
```

Type 'int' doesn't exist for serialization, you must use 'integer'.